# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources' - React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

I am getting error when I try to run the application. Attaching screenshots of errors.

Hoping to get the solution for this. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your gradle version to 3.5.4 in `android/build.gradle` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser/issues/287) and rebuild the app.

```
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4")
        // other stuff
    }
```

Comment: After upgrading the gradle now I am able to build successfully but the application is not opening in emulator. I am not seeing any errors in console as well @vinayr